# ScrollToEnd after update data for Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm making a chat box with `Flatlist`. I want to add a new item to data then scroll to bottom of list. I use `scrollToEnd` method but it did not work. How can I do this?

```js
<FlatList
        ref="flatList"
        data={this.state.data}
        extraData = {this.state}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.chatFlatListItem}>{item.chat}</Text>}
/>

AddChat(_chat){
    var arr = this.state.data;
    arr.push({key: arr.length, chat: _chat});
    var _data = {};
    _data["data"] = arr;
    this.setState(_data);
    this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd();
 }
```

Comment: is the data updated

Comment: Yes, the data is updated but the flatlist not scroll to bottom.

Comment: @TuanNguyenQuoc Can you try to add a timeout like so `setTimeout(() => this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd(), 200)`

Comment: your code is working with me so how you call AddChat()?

Comment: @Kernael: Thanks a lot. It's working!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found a better solution,`scrollToEnd()` is not working because it is triggered before the change is made to the `FlatList`.
Since it inherits from `ScrollView` the best way here is to call `scrollToEnd()` in `onContentSizeChange` like so :

```
<FlatList
            ref = "flatList"
            onContentSizeChange={()=> this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd()} />
```

Comment: unfortunately, this still doesn't work all the time. while it's cleaner than @tuan's solution, I found only his approach fixing the issue

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko Care to give at least one example after stating "doesn't work all the time"?

Comment: @Javascriptonian in my specific example, which I won't be able to find, unfortunately, only Tuan's approach worked. This one, on the opposite, worked not every single scroll.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks @Kernael, just add a timeout like so:

```
setTimeout(() => this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd(), 200)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
const flatList = React.useRef(null)
<FlatList
        ref={flatList}
        onContentSizeChange={() => {
            flatList.current.scrollToEnd();
        }}
        data={this.state.data}
        extraData = {this.state}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.chatFlatListItem}>{item.chat}</Text>}
/>
```

try this,it works.

Answer (score 4):

My issue here was that `scrollToEnd()` worked fine on mobile but on web it always scrolled to the top. Probably because I have elements with different size in the `FlatList` and couldn't define `getItemLayout`. But thanks to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55055163/2988107) here I solved it. Just with different approach.

```js
const ref = React.useRef<FlatList>();

function handleScrollToEnd(width, height) {
  if (ref.current) {
    ref.current.scrollToOffset({offset: height});
  }
}

<FlatList
  ref={ref}
  onContentSizeChange={handleScrollToEnd} 
/>
```

This works great on both the mobile and web. Hope it helps to somebody.

Comment: finally...an answer that actually works! lol

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below. The `ref` is modified and It's better to use `getItemLayout` in your `FlatList` according to [this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.48/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoend).

```
AddChat(_chat){
    var arr = this.state.data;
    arr.push({key: arr.length, chat: _chat});
    var _data = {};
    _data["data"] = arr;
    this.setState(_data);
    this.flatList.scrollToEnd();
 }

<FlatList
    ref={elm => this.flatList = elm}
    data={this.state.data}
    extraData = {this.state}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.chatFlatListItem}>{item.chat}</Text>}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
      {length: ITEM_HEIGHT, offset: ITEM_HEIGHT * index, index}
    )}
/>
```

**Note:** Replace the `ITEM_HEIGHT` with the real value of height of your list items.

Comment: This won't work if your items have a dynamic height. Actually, this will work, but with dynamic height, it's practically impossible to write `getItemLayout ` function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to use inverted prop on `Fatlist` itself
2. Pass your data like this `[...data].reverse()`
3. If you are at the middle of list and you need to scroll to end when a new item is added, just use:

   ```
   ref  => flatlistRef.current?.scrollToOffset({offset:0})
   ```

Answer (score 0):

seems caused by this line

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3da3d82320bd035c6bd361a82ea12a70dba4e851/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L1573

when use trigger scrollToEnd, frame.offset is 0

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3da3d82320bd035c6bd361a82ea12a70dba4e851/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L390

if you wait 1 second, _onContentSize changes and frame.offset is valorized (for ex. 1200 px).

Related post https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30373#issuecomment-1176199466

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a loader before Flatlist renders. For example:

```
const flatListRef = useRef(null);
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);


 if(!messages.length){
   return <Loader />
   }


return (
    <View style={styles.messagesContainer}>
      <FlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={messages}
        onContentSizeChange={() => {
          if (flatListRef.current) {

          flatListRef?.current?.scrollToEnd();

          }
        }}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
            <DisplayMessages
              message={item}
              index={index}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to end of flatlist if theres extra data or data loaded after some render, This works good for me with useref

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
export default function PatientConsentScreen({navigation, route}) {
  const scrollRef = useRef();
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={datatoload}
      extraData={datatoload}
      onContentSizeChange={() => {scrollRef.current.scrollToEnd(); }}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => {
        <Text style={{marginStart: 6, marginEnd: 36}}key={index}>{item.name}</Text>
      }}
    />
  )
}
```